# Cycles: Load image texture from memory

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm working with cycles standalone and I'm trying to find a way to use an image I already have loaded in memory as a texture in cycles.

From what I can see, the only way to load an image texture is with the ImageTextureNode, but that seems to only take a path to a file.

Is there some way built in to cycles to allow me to pass in a pointer to a bitmap in memory? My goal here is just to avoid needlessly writing out a temporary file to disk just so cycles can read it in again.

Comment: Small addition to clarify: When I say I'm working with cycles standalone, I am using a custom front-end. I'm not looking to get functionality like this through the xml API.

Comment: That would be off topic for here, you may want to chat with the devs on [irc #blendercoders](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community:Chat) as I expect the usage of cycles outside of blender is rather small so far. In blender the image selected in the image texture node (chosen from bpy.data.images[]) can exist only in memory and be sent to cycles. From python the [image object](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.pixels) has a pixels property that points to the image data in memory. You may be able to trace that through blender's code.

Comment: If nothing else works, you could creat a virtual disk in memory, and put textures there, even just for rendering. Never tried though.